# Add delay to animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

I'm using snap svg to load some svg icons, and some of them have 2/3 stops in the animation.
Is there anyway to add a delay with Snap like in Raphäel (the animation object has a delay method).

```
 var visualization = {
    init: function () {
      var tmp =  Snap.load('assets/js/svg/visualization.svg', visualization.loadVis);
    },
    loadVis: function(d){
      var tmp = d.select("#visualization");
      paperVis.append(d);
    },
    animate: function(){
      var flower = paperVis.select("#Flower");
    flower.attr({
      transform: 't0 30'
    });
    if (!flower.inAnim().length){
      flower.animate({transform: 't0 24'},300, mina.easein);
      flower.animate({transform: 't0 17'},300, mina.easein);
      flower.animate({transform: 't0 0'},300, mina.easein);
    }
  }
```

I'd like to know how do I add stops/delays to the animation. The animations are [here](http://www.behance.net/gallery/Simple-Animated-Icons/12269293).

Comment: Element.stop() to stop animation on an element as mentioned: http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.stop and regarding delay I think there is a property delayFactor not 100% sure tho.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a delay, but you could use setTimeout or something if not. It may help to see the svg (those on the links are gifs I think?), as it may depend if the svg has some animations inside it already or if they are purely controlled via Snap & JS.